# As400 System Reply List Entries questions

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have some questions about CHGRPYLE- System Reply List Entries

I want to try create some generic fixes to common issues in Legacy applications using CHGRPYLE, but have some questions....

- Is it possible to delay time before reply kicks in, say wait 3
  minutes before each reply?
- Is it possible to limit number of replies per per job?  eg: limit to
  3 or 6 automatic retries per job number?
- Is it possible apply retry to specific job names? or specific files
  only?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick way except writing your own message handler CL program to receive messages from the message queue and then reply to the message queue. Since you are writing your own handler you can go as creative as you want.